# jQuery Mobile dialog with form: after submitting $_POST is empty

Tags: forms, jquery-mobile, post, dialog

I have a problem reading the $_POST data after i submitted a form from a dialog.

The setup is like this:

Page1 (clientcard.php) contains a link to a dialog:

```
   <a href="addcontact.php?customer_id=169" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="flip" style="font-size: 9pt;" id="addcontact">Add new contact...</a>
```

Page 2 (the addcontact.php) posts the data to clientcard.php:

```
        <h3 style="margin-top: 0px;">Create contact</h3>
    <form method="POST" name="formaddcontact" id="formaddcontact" action="clientcard.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="client_ref" value="<?php echo $id;?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="mode" value="addcontact" />

        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
            <li class="ui-field-contain">
                <label for="naam">name:</label>
                <input name="naam" id="naam" value="" data-clear-btn="false" type="text" />
            </li>
            <li class="ui-field-contain">
                <label for="functie_ref">Department:</label>
                <select name="functie_ref" id="functie_ref" data-native-menu="false">
<!-- some options -->
                </select>
            </li>
            <li class="ui-field-contain">
                <label for="telefoon">Phone:</label>
                <input name="telefoon" id="telefoon" value="" data-clear-btn="false" type="text" />
            </li>
            <li class="ui-field-contain">
                <label for="mobiel">Cell:</label>
                <input name="mobiel" id="mobiel" value="" data-clear-btn="false" type="text" />
            </li>
            <li class="ui-field-contain">
                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                <input name="email" id="email" value="" data-clear-btn="false" type="text" />
            </li>
            <li class="ui-body ui-body-b">
                <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
                        <div class="ui-block-a"><a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="a">Annuleren</a></div>
                        <div class="ui-block-b"><a href="javascript:this.formaddcontact.submit();" data-rel="submit" data-role="button" data-theme="b">Opslaan</a></div>
                </fieldset>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
```

I read in other answers that you have to use something like `parent().appendTo($("form:first"));`but to be honest i have NO clue where to put that...
I use jquery mobile 1.4.3 and the jquery code that is actually popping up the dialog is generated by jqm and i have no `<script>` code whatsoever in my files...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Regards, Christiaan

Comment: Apparently i was lost in too much code. I had 2 declarations of forms with the same name. it was appending to the wrong form. All fixed now